# Salesforce How to perform Tree Structure records Deep Clone?

Tags: apex

Object   Node__Object__c    has a lookup field to itself.

So it's like I have a n-ary tree that every record tracks its parent except for the root.

What is a good way to perform a deep clone of the records and their relationships considering the governor limits?

height 2 tree example:

A->D,B->D,C->D,

after the operation,

A->D,B->D,C->D,
copyA->copyD,copyB->copyD,copyC->copyD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/salesforce-true-deep-clone-the-impossible-dream/) is a good example of how to do it. It clones the records, relationships and maintains parent-child relationships to preserve the tree structure. You can use the class as is and call the `deepCloneBatched()` method for cloning out the tree.

It works with both custom and standard objects. Relevant method provided below, for full source code - see the provided link

```
 public static list<sObject> deepCloneBatched(list<sObject> objectsToClone, map<id,id> previousSourceToCloneMap)
    {
        system.debug('\n\n\n--------------------  Cloning record ' + objectsToClone.size() + ' records');
        list<id> objectIds = new list<id>();
        list<sobject> clones = new list<sobject>();
        list<sObject> newClones = new list<sObject>();
        map<id,id> sourceToCloneMap = new map<id,id>();


        if(objectsToClone.isEmpty())
        {
            system.debug('\n\n\n-------------------- No records in set to clone. Aborting');
            return clones;
        }

        //if this function has been called recursively, then the previous batch of cloned records
        //have not been inserted yet, so now they must be before we can continue. Also, in that case
        //because these are already clones, we do not need to clone them again, so we can skip that part
        if(objectsToClone[0].Id == null)
        {
            //if they don't have an id that means these records are already clones. So just insert them with no need to clone beforehand.
            insert objectsToClone;
            clones.addAll(objectsToClone);

            for(sObject thisClone : clones)
            {
                sourceToCloneMap.put(thisClone.getCloneSourceId(),thisClone.Id);
            }

            objectIds.addAll(new list<id>(previousSourceToCloneMap.keySet()));
            //get the ids of all these objects.                    
        }
        else
        {
            //get the ids of all these objects.
            for(sObject thisObj :objectsToClone)
            {
                objectIds.add(thisObj.Id);
            }

            for(sObject thisObj : objectsToClone)
            {
                sObject clonedObject = thisObj.clone(false,true,false,false);
                clones.add(clonedObject);               
            }    

            //insert the clones
            insert clones;

            for(sObject thisClone : clones)
            {
                sourceToCloneMap.put(thisClone.getCloneSourceId(),thisClone.Id);
            }
        }        

        //figure out what kind of object we are dealing with
        string relatedObjectType = objectsToClone[0].Id.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();

        //Describes this object type so we can deduce it's child relationships
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = globalDescribeMap.get(relatedObjectType).getDescribe();

        //get this objects child relationship types
        List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childRelationships = objectDescribe.getChildRelationships();

        system.debug('\n\n\n-------------------- ' + objectDescribe.getName() + ' has ' + childRelationships.size() + ' child relationships');

        //then have to iterate over every child relationship type, and every record of that type and clone them as well. 
        for(Schema.ChildRelationship thisRelationship : childRelationships)
        { 

            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult childObjectDescribe = thisRelationship.getChildSObject().getDescribe();
            string relationshipField = thisRelationship.getField().getDescribe().getName();

            try
            {
                system.debug('\n\n\n-------------------- Looking at ' + childObjectDescribe.getName() + ' which is a child object of ' + objectDescribe.getName());

                if(!childObjectDescribe.isCreateable() || !childObjectDescribe.isQueryable() || !childObjectDescribe.isCustom())
                {
                    system.debug('-------------------- Object is not one of the following: queryable, creatable, or custom. Skipping attempting to clone this object');
                    continue;
                }
                if(Limits.getQueries() >= Limits.getLimitQueries())
                {
                    system.debug('\n\n\n-------------------- Governor limits hit. Must abort.');
                    return clones;
                }
                //create a select all query from the child object type
                string childDataQuery = buildSelectAllStatment(childObjectDescribe.getName());

                //add a where condition that will only find records that are related to this record. The field which the relationship is defined is stored in the maps value
                childDataQuery+= ' where '+relationshipField+ ' in :objectIds';

                //get the details of this object
                list<sObject> childObjectsWithData = database.query(childDataQuery);

                if(!childObjectsWithData.isEmpty())
                {               
                    map<id,id> childRecordSourceToClone = new map<id,id>();

                    for(sObject thisChildObject : childObjectsWithData)
                    {
                        childRecordSourceToClone.put(thisChildObject.Id,null);

                        //clone the object
                        sObject newClone = thisChildObject.clone();

                        //since the record we cloned still has the original parent id, we now need to update the clone with the id of it's cloned parent.
                        //to do that we reference the map we created above and use it to get the new cloned parent.                        
                        system.debug('\n\n\n----------- Attempting to change parent of clone....');
                        id newParentId = sourceToCloneMap.get((id) thisChildObject.get(relationshipField));

                        system.debug('Old Parent: ' + thisChildObject.get(relationshipField) + ' new parent ' + newParentId);

                        //write the new parent value into the record
                        newClone.put(thisRelationship.getField().getDescribe().getName(),newParentId );

                        //add this new clone to the list. It will be inserted once the deepClone function is called again. I know it's a little odd to not just insert them now
                        //but it save on redudent logic in the long run.
                        newClones.add(newClone);             
                    }  
                    //now we need to call this function again, passing in the newly cloned records, so they can be inserted, as well as passing in the ids of the original records
                    //that spawned them so the next time the query can find the records that currently exist that are related to the kind of records we just cloned.                
                    clones.addAll(deepCloneBatched(newClones,childRecordSourceToClone));                                  
                }                    
            }
            catch(exception e)
            {
                system.debug('\n\n\n---------------------- Error attempting to clone child records of type: ' + childObjectDescribe.getName());
                system.debug(e); 
            }            
        }

        return clones;
    }
```